# How to get attribute values of an app client in Cognito User Pools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I would like to get the values of attributes of app clients defined in Cognito user pools. I'm able to get the list of attributes using [describe-user-pool-client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.describe_user_pool_client). However, I haven't found a way to get the values.

Comment: do you mean getting information/data about the user logged in?

Comment: Did you check the response of describe-user-pool-client. ( 'SchemaAttributes':) ?

Comment: It only returns the read and write attribute name, not values.

Comment: The attribute values are properties of the users in your user pool, not the client. You would need to query a particular user to see the attribute values

Comment: @BrianWinant We can update attribute values for app client using update_user_pool_client (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.update_user_pool_client)

Comment: Can you explain what "attribute values" you are referring to? The app client definition only contains the names of the read/write attributes - think of it as a schema definition. If you want to know what values those attributes have, you have to query users